# net:ERR_FAILED - My application (Ionic 4 / Angular 7) is giving an error when trying to export a Highcharts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, highcharts, angular7, ionic4

Below is the image of the error that occurs every time having to download the graphic, either in PDF, png, JPEG ...

[Photo Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWhNl.jpg)

My view.module.ts is:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';   

import Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting.src.js'; 

Exporting(Highcharts);
```

in my view.html:

```
<ion-header class="ion-header">
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.0.3/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.0.3/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.0.3/highcharts-more.js"></script>
</ion-header>
```

in my view.ts:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

async chartAIM() {
        this.graficoAIM = Highcharts.chart("containerAIM", {options});}
```

where in options:

```
 exporting: {
            enabled: true,
            csv: {
                itemDelimiter: ','
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the URL of the [Highcharts export script](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview) isn't right. Are you working through a proxy?

Here are available links:

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>  
<!-- optional -->  
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>  
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

P.S.: Please edit your post with detailed informations, code examples and so on. Don't put huge links to your screenshots.

Also, providing a link to a demo of what you actually got is a must.